# Align equations at more than one point

Tags: equations, align, arrays, split

I have got the following set of equations:
[image]

which corresponds to the following code:

```
 \begin{align}
  \begin{split}
     a_1 + b_1 \xi + c_1 \xi^2 + d_1 \xi^3 &= a_2 + b_2 \xi + c_2 \xi^2 + d_2 \xi^3 \\
     b_1 + 2c_1 \xi + 3d_1 \xi^2 &= b_2 + 2c_2 \xi + 3d_2 \xi^2 \\
     2 c_1 + 6 d_1 \xi &= 2c_2 + 6 d_2 \xi, 
 \end{split}
\end{align}
```

I want all three equations to start at the same point, such that it would look something like this: [image]

Is this possible?

Comment: use `\begin{alignedat}{2}`+`\end{alignedat}` instead of split, place `&` at the start of every row, and `&&` before the `=`.

Comment: Next time please make sure to post full minimal examples including document class and a minimal preamble. That makes it a lot easier to test your code. Here we have to guess a lot of stuff before being able to test it.

Comment: BTW: I'd probably use `equation` at the outer layer, not `align`

Comment: You could also minipage it, if you know the endpoint of your equations.

Comment: Awesome, this works; thank you daleif! Next time I will include the document class etc :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `alignedat` instead of `split` and keep track of the `&`'s

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{alignedat}{2}
     &a_1 + b_1 \xi + c_1 \xi^2 + d_1 \xi^3 &&= a_2 + b_2 \xi + c_2 \xi^2 + d_2 \xi^3 \\
     &b_1 + 2c_1 \xi + 3d_1 \xi^2 &&= b_2 + 2c_2 \xi + 3d_2 \xi^2 \\
     &2 c_1 + 6 d_1 \xi &&= 2c_2 + 6 d_2 \xi, 
 \end{alignedat}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```